# VS2013: How to publish a folder that is not part of my project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an asp.net mvc project in visual studio 2013.
I'm using gulp to take some "source" js files from one folder and output the "built" files to a /Scripts folder.
I'd like to publish the /Scripts folder to my production server.
As the /Scripts folder and it's contents are not part of my project (to avoid TFS issues), is there a way to publish the /Scripts folder and it's content?

**Update**:
The /Scripts folder is not part of my project because these are output files generated by gulp and so it didn't make sense to have these as part of my project and checked in to TFS. Also, if I did, then I'd have issues running the gulp task due to the files being checked-in in the output folder.

**Update 2**
[I may have found an answer.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files)
I'll update tomorrow once I can test at work.

Comment: What issues in TFS are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files).

Within VS2013 solution explorer:

1. Expanded the web project.
2. Expanded the Properties node.
3. Expanded the PublishProfiles folder.
4. Selected the xml file for the profile I wanted to edit.
5. Pasted the following just before the closing `</Project>` tag. (This is the working code, cut and pasted.)

```xml
<Target Name="CustomCopyScripts">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="Scripts\**\*" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<!-- Configure when to run the above custom task. -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>CustomCopyScripts; ;
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>CustomCopyScripts; ;
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```